# Microsoft Graph Notification Subscription for photo change

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking through the Microsoft documentation on `Subscription` objects (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks). I want to receive a notification for when a user changes their Profile Picture (photo property)

I sent the following subscription request, and I am successful in receiving notification when I update user properties, but not when I change their picture:

```
POST /v1.0/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>

{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://00000.ngrok.io/listen",
  "resource": "/users",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-12-09T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "resource": "/users",
    "applicationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "changeType": "updated",
    "clientState": "SecretClientState",
    "notificationUrl": "https://00000.ngrok.io/listen",
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-12-09T11:00:00Z",
    "creatorId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "includeResourceData": null,
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
    "encryptionCertificate": null,
    "encryptionCertificateId": null
}
```

Is there a way to subscript to photo changes in the Microsoft Graph in aggregate?  Or do I have to subscribe to each user individually?

Comment: In general, reading and updating a user's profile photo is only possible if the user has a mailbox. Additionally, any photos that may have been previously stored using the thumbnailPhoto property (using the Azure AD Graph or through AD Connect synchronization) are no longer accessible through the Microsoft Graph photo property of the user resource.

Comment: @Dev do you have a link to the documentation that describes what you commented? I have an AAD that is tied to my corporate email and when I call for the /me/photo/$value graph object, I get back my profile picture.

Comment: here's the closest documentation [Microsoft Graph API limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues) talks about it, refer "photo restrictions" section

Comment: I will move the above to answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well. Also i will watch out for other answers as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading and updating a user's profile photo is only possible if the user has a mailbox. Additionally, any photos that may have been previously stored using the thumbnailPhoto property (using the Azure AD Graph or through AD Connect synchronization) are no longer accessible through the Microsoft Graph photo property of the user resource. Microsoft documentation [Microsoft Graph API limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues) talks about it, refer "photo restrictions" section.

Comment: I think the documentation is misleading.  I have an AAD that doesn't have any O365 mailboxes and I can add and remove user photos for all the users.  I can PUT photo data into the `/user/ID/photo` API endpoint and then retrieve it by calling GET on `/user/ID/photo/$value`.  I've tried it across multiple AAD tenants and each one works.  I was also able to do all of that using the Microsoft Graph Explorer tool as well: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Since the points are going to be wasted, I'll give them to you. I still think there is another answer that works better.